# upgrade PHP 7 to PHP 8.2 in LAMPP Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, lampp, php-8.2

My LAMPP is running PHP 7.4.33 and want to upgrade to php 8.2 and the problem is the server is offline and no internet connection, so i must download on other server and copy to offline server, and is that possible to upgrade to PHP 8.2 without reinstall LAMPP ?

i tried to follow from internet but ist difficult to find a download link for php8.x Thread Safe

Comment: How do you use that server if it is offline?